# Pivot on multiple columns with same data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, aggregate-functions

I have set of data

[image]

How can I achieve something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select targetchildid,
    max(case when name = 'Hepatitis B #1' then datereceived   end) as hepatitis_b1_date_received,
    max(case when name = 'Hepatitis B #1' then ajustedduedate end) as hepatitis_b1_adjusted_due_date,
    max(case when name = 'Hepatitis B #1' then isskipped      end) as hepatitis_b1_adjusted_is_skipped,
    max(case when name = 'Hepatitis B #2' then datereceived   end) as hepatitis_b2_date_received,
    max(case when name = 'Hepatitis B #2' then ajustedduedate end) as hepatitis_b2_adjusted_due_date,
    max(case when name = 'Hepatitis B #2' then isskipped      end) as hepatitis_b2_adjusted_is_skipped,
    max(case when name = 'Hepatitis B #3' then datereceived   end) as hepatitis_b3_date_received,
    max(case when name = 'Hepatitis B #3' then ajustedduedate end) as hepatitis_b3_adjusted_due_date,
    max(case when name = 'Hepatitis B #3' then isskipped      end) as hepatitis_b3_adjusted_is_skipped
from mytable
group by targetchildid
```